# Hosted DNS provider with templates, mass updates, etc?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain-name, dns-hosting

We need to setup DNS for a relatively large number of domain names (50-60), most of which will have an identical zone setup (except for the stuff that /has/ to change on a per-domain basis).

Is there a hosted DNS provider out there that offers features like:

1) Zone templates - i.e. create a standard set of DNS records once, and then apply that template to one or more domain names, automatically inserting / changing bits that are domain-specific.

2) Mass-updating - i.e. say we need to change the "root" A record on 50 domains from "domain.name = 1.2.3.4" to "domain.name = "4.3.2.1", a feature which lets us apply this across all 50 domains in one go rather than updating each domain individually.

Are these sorts of features available? If so, can anyone recommend a reliable hosted DNS service that offers them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question - or at least provide one option: we found and signed up with Zerigo, who offer both of the features we were after.

Answer (score 1):

www.EuroDNS.com does all of this.

We've used them for a few years, always been good.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but it looks like they only offer their DNS services for domains registered through them. We're after a third-party provider we can use with domains registered elsewhere.